# Pandas UDF (PySpark) - Incorrect type Error

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, spacy

I'm trying entity extraction with spaCy and Pandas UDF (PySpark) but I get an error.
Using a UDF works without errors but is slow. What am I doing wrong?

Loading the model every time is to avoid load error -  `Can't find model 'en_core_web_lg'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.`

**Working UDF:**

```
def __get_entities(x):

    global nlp
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
    ents=[]

    doc = nlp(x)

    for ent in doc.ents:
        if ent.label_ == 'PERSON' OR ent.label_ == 'ORG':
            ents.append(ent.label_)

    return ents

get_entities_udf = F.udf(__get_entities), T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
```

**Pandas UDF with error:**

```
def __get_entities(x):

    global nlp
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
    ents=[]

    doc = nlp(x)

    for ent in doc.ents:
        if ent.label_ == 'PERSON' OR ent.label_ == 'ORG':
            ents.append(ent.label_)

    return pd.Series(ents)


get_entities_udf = F.pandas_udf(lambda x: __get_entities(x), "array<string>", F.PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
```

**Error message:**

```
TypeError: Argument 'string'has incorrect type (expected str, got series)
```

**Sample Spark DataFrame:**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ['John Doe'],
  ['Jane Doe'],
  ['Microsoft Corporation'],
  ['Apple Inc.'],
]).toDF("name",)
```

**New column:**

```
df_new = df.withColumn('entity',get_entities_udf('name'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to see the input as `pd.Series` instead of single value

I was able to get it working by refactoring the code a bit. Notice `x.apply` call which is pandas specific and applies function to a `pd.Series`.

```
def entities(x):
    global nlp
    import spacy
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
    ents=[]

    doc = nlp(x)

    for ent in doc.ents:
        if ent.label_ == 'PERSON' or ent.label_ == 'ORG':
            ents.append(ent.label_)
    return ents


def __get_entities(x):
    return x.apply(entities)

get_entities_udf = pandas_udf(lambda x: __get_entities(x), "array<string>", PandasUDFType.SCALAR)

df_new = df.withColumn('entity',get_entities_udf('name'))

df_new.show()

+--------------------+--------+
|                name|  entity|
+--------------------+--------+
|            John Doe|[PERSON]|
|            Jane Doe|[PERSON]|
|Microsoft Corpora...|   [ORG]|
|          Apple Inc.|   [ORG]|
+--------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using: **pyspark 3.1.1** and **python 3.7**

The answer above didn't work for me, I and spend quite some time making things work, so I thought I'd share the solution I came up with.

## Setting things up

creating a sample of 16 random person and company names

```py
import pandas as pd

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

from faker import Faker
import spacy

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("pyspark_sandbox").getOrCreate()

names = []
fake = Faker()
for _ in range(8):
    names.append(f"{fake.company()} {fake.company_suffix()}")
    names.append(fake.name())

df = spark.createDataFrame(names, StringType())
```

## As it is

First, checking the current solution proposed. I'm just Adding a print statement upon loading the spacy model to see how many time we do load the model.

```py
# printing a msg each time we load the model
def load_spacy_model():
    print("Loading spacy model...")
    return spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

def entities(x):
    global nlp
    import spacy
    nlp = load_spacy_model()
    ents=[]

    doc = nlp(x)

    for ent in doc.ents:
        if ent.label_ == 'PERSON' or ent.label_ == 'ORG':
            ents.append(ent.label_)
    return ents


def __get_entities(x):
    return x.apply(entities)

get_entities_udf = pandas_udf(lambda x: __get_entities(x), "array<string>", PandasUDFType.SCALAR)

df_new = df.withColumn('entity',get_entities_udf('value'))

df_new.show()
```

We can then see that the model is loaded **16 times**, so one for every single entry we process. Not what I want.

## Batch processing

Rewriting using the decorator introduce in **spark 3.0+** that is using Type Hints (**python 3.6+**). Then our UDF is using the nlp.pipe() for batch processing the entire pd.Series

```py
# printing a msg each time we load the model
def load_spacy_model():
    print("Loading spacy model...")
    return spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# decorator indicating that this function is pandas_udf
# and that it's gonna process list of string
@pandas_udf(ArrayType(StringType()))
# function receiving a pd.Series and returning a pd.Series
def entities(list_of_text: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    global nlp
    nlp = load_spacy_model()
    docs = nlp.pipe(list_of_text)

    # retrieving the str representation of entity label
    # as we are limited in the types of obj
    # we can return from a panda_udf
    # we couldn't return a Span obj for example
    ents=[
        [ent.label_ for ent in doc.ents]
        for doc in docs
    ]
    return pd.Series(ents)


df_new = df.withColumn('entity',entities('value'))

df_new.show()
```

In my case the model was loaded 4 times, that's better. It's each time a python worker is created to process a batch. So the number will depend how many cores is Spark using but more critically in my case: how much **partitioned** is our data. So it's yet to be optimum

## broadcasting the `nlp` object

```py
# printing a msg each time we load the model
def load_spacy_model():
    print("Loading spacy model...")
    return spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

@pandas_udf(ArrayType(StringType()))
def entities(list_of_text: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    nlp = boardcasted_nlp.value
    docs = nlp.pipe(list_of_text)

    # retrieving the str representation of entity label
    # as we are limited in the types of obj
    # we can return from a panda_udf
    # we couldn't return a Span obj for example
    ents=[
        [ent.label_ for ent in doc.ents]
        for doc in docs
    ]
    return pd.Series(ents)

boardcasted_nlp = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(load_spacy_model())

df_new = df.withColumn('entity',entities('value'))

df_new.show()
```

Now the model is loaded **only once** then broadcasted to every python worker that is getting spawned.

## The complete Code

```py
import pandas as pd

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

from faker import Faker
import spacy

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("pyspark_sandbox").getOrCreate()

# creating our set of fake person and company names
names = []
fake = Faker()
for _ in range(8):
    names.append(f"{fake.company()} {fake.company_suffix()}")
    names.append(fake.name())

df = spark.createDataFrame(names, StringType())

# printing a msg each time we load the model
def load_spacy_model():
    print("Loading spacy model...")
    return spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# decorator indicating that this function is pandas_udf
# and that it's gonna process list of string
@pandas_udf(ArrayType(StringType()))
# function receiving a pd.Series and returning a pd.Series
def entities(list_of_text: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    # retrieving the shared nlp object
    nlp = boardcasted_nlp.value
    # batch processing our list of text
    docs = nlp.pipe(list_of_text)
    
    # retrieving the str representation of entity label
    # as we are limited in the types of obj
    # we can return from a panda_udf
    # we couldn't return a Span obj for example
    ents=[
        [ent.label_ for ent in doc.ents]
        for doc in docs
    ]
    return pd.Series(ents)

# we load the spacy model and broadcast it
boardcasted_nlp = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(load_spacy_model())

df_new = df.withColumn('entity',entities('value'))

df_new.show(truncate=False)
```

**Result**

```
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|value                             |entity                          |
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|Ferguson, Price and Green Ltd     |[ORG, ORG, ORG]                 |
|Cassandra Goodman MD              |[PERSON]                        |
|Solis Ltd LLC                     |[ORG]                           |
|Laurie Foster                     |[PERSON]                        |
|Lane-Vasquez Group                |[ORG]                           |
|Matthew Wright                    |[PERSON]                        |
|Scott, Pugh and Rodriguez and Sons|[PERSON, PERSON, PERSON, PERSON]|
|Tina Cooke                        |[PERSON]                        |
|Watkins, Blake and Foster Ltd     |[ORG]                           |
|Charles Reyes                     |[PERSON]                        |
|Cooper, Norris and Roberts PLC    |[ORG]                           |
|Michael Tate                      |[PERSON]                        |
|Powell, Lawson and Perez and Sons |[PERSON, PERSON, PERSON, PERSON]|
|James Wolf PhD                    |[PERSON]                        |
|Greer-Swanson PLC                 |[ORG]                           |
|Nicholas Hale                     |[PERSON]                        |
+----------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: Neat solution. Thanks!